# nightmareJS timeout on vagrant

Tags: node.js, npm, vagrant, nightmare, codeceptjs

I have vagrant virtualmachine, I can access some endpoints from there (via curl). I installed node (v 8.4.0) and npm (v 5.3.0). I run it via sudo. I use nightmareJS and it can't connect to endpoint. I run the same tests case on other machine and it works without timeout:

**test/test_simple.js**

```
const Nightmare = require('nightmare')

describe('UI Flow Tests', function() {
  this.timeout('60s')

  let nightmare = null
  beforeEach(() => {
    nightmare = new Nightmare()
  })



  describe('Using the App', function () {
    describe('customize', () => {
      it('should work without timing out', done => {
        nightmare
        .goto('http://simple-form-bootstrap.plataformatec.com.br/documentation')
        .end()
        .then(result => { done() })
        .catch(done)
      })
    })
  })
})
```

when I run:

```
sudo npm test
```

then there is a timeout:

```
> codec@1.0.0 test /home/vagrant/project/codecept
> mocha



  UI Flow Tests
    Using the App
      customize
        1) should work without timing out


  0 passing (1m)
  1 failing

  1) UI Flow Tests Using the App customize should work without timing out:
     Error: Timeout of 60000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.




npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

*Edit*

I tried node v8.3.0 and nightmare 2.8 and 2.4.1 but the same error. Looks like vagrant is blocking request(?)

*Edit2*
I ran nightmare in debug node and I get error with electron:
`DEBUG=nightmare npm test`

`nightmare electron child process exited with code 127: command not found - you may not have electron installed correctly +0ms
  nightmare queueing action "goto" for http://simple-form-bootstrap.plataformatec.com.br/documentation +3ms
  nightmare running +2ms`

*Edit3*
deguggin electron gives:

  `electron:stderr /home/vagrant/te/node_modules/electron/dist/electron: error while loading shared libraries: libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: I can reproduce the issue on their example also, so probably some bug with the latest version?

Comment: @TarunLalwani I update question, downgrade didn't help

Comment: I tried mac, vm, docker and nothing worked. Something to do with electron setup i guess

Answer (score 0):

I had to install libxss1 libnspr4-0d libcurl3, libx11-xcb-dev. Maybe not all libs are required.